# Problems with gnome-shell Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, gnome, graphics

I've installed Ubuntu 17.10 alongside with Win10 on my laptop, but it works very slowly although my laptop has Core i5 7-th Gen, 16gb ram, gtx1060-6gb. The animations are very slow, page scrolling isn't smooth and all windows render slowly from top of the window to bottom. I think the problem is in gnome-shell or my graphics card drivers, because after I killed the gnome-shell process, mozilla worked perfectly.

I've tried to install proprietary drivers (and nvidia prime after that) for my nvidia card, but after installing I can't even boot in Ubuntu - I get `Stopping User Manager for UID 121...`. So I deleted them in recovery mode.

Why the system works so badly? What should I do?

Comment: You should install Nvidia drivers for the GTX1060 just like you (or the manufacturer) did in Windows. The difference is in Ubuntu it's easier. Open Additional Drivers and simply select and apply the recommended version. But before that make sure to undo the previous installation by running `sudo apt purge nvidia*`.

Comment: @MichaelBay, I didn't installed any drivers in Windows - Windows did it itself. I've already tried to install the proprietary driver from the "Software and Upates"->"Additional drivers", but I get the problem while boot, which I described in my question.

Comment: Seems Graphics has always been a stumbling point with "Ubuntu".